# MYSQL Range returning values not in a ranges

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where I am querying the database directly for some operations.

I currently have a mysql statment like this.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM yumba_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'Price' AND meta_value > 1 AND meta_value < 625000
```

This is all fine and dandy except it returns yes a range but also values that are int eh millions.

Here is a sample of the data it returns.

```
"post_id"   "meta_value"

"46211" "7000"
"46212" "7000"
"46213" "7000"
"46214" "7000"
"46215" "7000"
"46216" "7000"
"46217" "7000"
"46218" "7000"
"46219" "7000"
"46220" "7000"
"46221" "7000"
"46222" "7000"
"46223" "7000"
"46224" "7000"
"46225" "7000"
"46226" "7000"
"46227" "7000"
"46228" "7000"
"46229" "7000"
"46268" "7000"
"30305" "7500"
"30435" "7500"
"30599" "7500"
"30603" "7500"
"30597" "7900"
"30971" "8000"
"46232" "8000"
"46236" "8000"
"30579" "8300"
"30433" "8500"
"30437" "8500"
"30755" "8500"
"30860" "8500"
"36192" "8500"
"46171" "8500"
"45026" "8900"
"30426" "8950"
"29909" "9000"
"30124" "9000"
"30384" "9000"
"30608" "9000"
"30436" "9500"
"46054" "9540"
"30344" "9750"
"30805" "9800"
"30014" "9900"
"30015" "9900"
"30016" "9900"
"30017" "9900"
"46153" "9900"
"46154" "9900"
"46155" "9900"
"46156" "9900"
"46288" "9900"
"29982" "10000"
"30038" "10000"
"30057" "10000"
"30223" "10000"
"30429" "10000"
"30434" "10000"
"30493" "10000"
"30698" "10000"
"30839" "10000"
"45558" "10000"
"45717" "10000"
"46241" "10000"
"46267" "10000"
"46287" "10900"
"36204" "11000"
"30529" "11390"
"30728" "11500"
"46250" "11500"
"46102" "11700"
"30371" "12000"
"30703" "12000"
"30858" "12000"
"46141" "12000"
"46142" "12000"
"46240" "12000"
"46260" "12000"
"30258" "12500"
"30308" "12500"
"45009" "12500"
"46094" "12900"
"43295" "13000"
"45908" "13000"
"46253" "13200"
"46254" "13200"
"30795" "13750"
"36199" "13900"
"46247" "13900"
"46292" "13900"
"30386" "14000"
"46251" "14200"
"36226" "14500"
"30580" "14900"
"30877" "14900"
"30887" "14900"
"46098" "14900"
"46151" "14900"
"43221" "14950"
"45477" "14950"
"30185" "14995"
"133"   "15000"
"29902" "15000"
"29997" "15000"
"30019" "15000"
"30041" "15000"
"30042" "15000"
"30043" "15000"
"30044" "15000"
"30528" "15000"
"30583" "15000"
"30814" "15000"
"30849" "15000"
"30889" "15000"
"30918" "15000"
"30919" "15000"
"45462" "15000"
"45713" "15000"
"46010" "15000"
"46286" "15000"
"30732" "15500"
"46143" "15500"
"46144" "15500"
"46145" "15500"
"46146" "15500"
"46147" "15500"
"46148" "15500"
"30331" "15900"
"30275" "16000"
"30704" "16000"
"30944" "16100"
"30930" "16200"
"789"   "16384"
"30927" "16400"
"30946" "16400"
"30465" "16500"
"46237" "16500"
"46239" "16500"
"30948" "16600"
"30712" "16700"
"44906" "16900"
"45173" "16900"
"45328" "16900"
"28"    "17000"
"29975" "17000"
"30059" "17000"
"31031" "17000"
"30945" "17200"
"30947" "17200"
"30931" "17300"
"30314" "17500"
"30926" "17500"
"30968" "17500"
"30969" "17500"
"30888" "17800"
"30939" "17800"
"30941" "17800"
"30182" "17900"
"43136" "19900"
"44929" "19900"
"45458" "19900"
"46118" "19900"
"46152" "19900"
"30742" "19950"
"30265" "20000"
"30385" "20000"
"30388" "20000"
"30683" "20000"
"30832" "20000"
"30847" "20000"
"30848" "20000"
"31284" "20000"
"43156" "20000"
"45931" "20000"
"45943" "20000"
"46001" "20000"
"46187" "20000"
"46188" "20000"
"46191" "20000"
"46192" "20000"
"46193" "20000"
"46284" "20000"
"29977" "20500"
"29996" "21000"
"30582" "21000"
"30809" "21000"
"45779" "21000"
"45852" "21000"
"29851" "21400"
"29875" "21900"
"30380" "21900"
"32478" "21900"
"46150" "21900"
"30266" "22000"
"30267" "22000"
"30396" "22000"
"30864" "22000"
"32101" "22000"
"30135" "22500"
"30136" "22500"
"30334" "22500"
"30921" "22500"
"29109" "22528"
"30933" "22800"
"30029" "22900"
"30030" "22900"
"30031" "22900"
"43211" "22900"
"30885" "23000"
"164"   "23200"
"45451" "23312"
"29907" "23500"
"29948" "23500"
"29951" "23500"
"30033" "23500"
"30035" "23500"
"30419" "23500"
"43125" "23500"
"45587" "23500"
"46244" "23500"
"46064" "23600"
"30937" "23800"
"29984" "23900"
"45970" "23990"
"30225" "24000"
"30227" "24000"
"30228" "24000"
"30229" "24000"
"30243" "24000"
"30280" "24000"
"30807" "24000"
"30899" "24000"
"36206" "24000"
"36207" "24000"
"36208" "24000"
"36209" "24000"
"36210" "24000"
"36211" "24000"
"36212" "24000"
"36213" "24000"
"36214" "24000"
"36215" "24000"
"36216" "24000"
"45532" "24000"
"45533" "24000"
"46003" "24000"
"46025" "24000"
"29983" "24500"
"30011" "24500"
"30338" "24500"
"30935" "24800"
"29167" "24900"
"29628" "24900"
"30156" "24900"
"30157" "24900"
"30158" "24900"
"30159" "24900"
"30161" "24900"
"30162" "24900"
"30163" "24900"
"30164" "24900"
"30186" "24900"
"30244" "24900"
"30348" "24900"
"36232" "24900"
"43416" "24900"
"45295" "24900"
"29897" "25000"
"29898" "25000"
"29899" "25000"
"29900" "25000"
"30034" "25000"
"30109" "25000"
"30260" "25000"
"30352" "25000"
"30377" "25000"
"30450" "25000"
"30531" "25000"
"30532" "25000"
"30533" "25000"
"30534" "25000"
"30535" "25000"
"30536" "25000"
"30537" "25000"
"30538" "25000"
"30539" "25000"
"30540" "25000"
"30541" "25000"
"30542" "25000"
"30543" "25000"
"30544" "25000"
"30545" "25000"
"30546" "25000"
"30547" "25000"
"30548" "25000"
"30549" "25000"
"30550" "25000"
"30551" "25000"
"30552" "25000"
"30559" "25000"
"30663" "25000"
"30692" "25000"
"30693" "25000"
"30694" "25000"
"30695" "25000"
"30769" "25000"
"30883" "25000"
"30959" "25000"
"30960" "25000"
"30961" "25000"
"30962" "25000"
"31037" "25000"
"31327" "25000"
"32339" "25000"
"36193" "25000"
"36194" "25000"
"36195" "25000"
"36510" "25000"
"43124" "25000"
"45017" "25000"
"29974" "29900"
"30032" "29900"
"30160" "29900"
"30165" "29900"
"30166" "29900"
"30194" "29900"
"30500" "29900"
"30574" "29900"
"30696" "29900"
"30715" "29900"
"30719" "29900"
"30757" "29900"
"30835" "29900"
"30875" "29900"
"30876" "29900"
"32515" "29900"
"36191" "29900"
"45020" "29900"
"45739" "29900"
"45781" "29900"
"45861" "29900"
"45920" "29900"
"46043" "29900"
"46093" "29900"
"46243" "29900"
"30745" "29950"
"356"   "30000"
"29712" "30000"
"29912" "30000"
"29913" "30000"
"29914" "30000"
"29922" "30000"
"30173" "30000"
"30402" "30000"
"30949" "30000"
"31109" "30000"
"31339" "30000"
"45006" "30000"
"45012" "30000"
"45014" "30000"
"45720" "30000"
"46000" "30000"
"29879" "30900"
"179"   "31000"
"180"   "31000"
"46149" "31000"
"46166" "31300"
"32473" "31500"
"307"   "31900"
"32562" "31950"
"998"   "32000"
"30339" "32000"
"36324" "32000"
"29186" "32500"
"30657" "38000"
"31185" "38000"
"43017" "38000"
"43474" "38000"
"30074" "38300"
"30078" "38375"
"29877" "38400"
"30069" "38400"
"30070" "38425"
"30060" "38500"
"30061" "38500"
"30062" "38500"
"30067" "38500"
"30068" "38500"
"30076" "38500"
"30077" "38500"
"30395" "38500"
"43039" "38500"
"30075" "38550"
"30066" "38700"
"30071" "38700"
"29272" "38900"
"30065" "38900"
"30072" "38900"
"32404" "38900"
"29355" "39000"
"30073" "39000"
"30221" "39000"
"30492" "39000"
"30818" "39000"
"31330" "39000"
"31420" "39000"
"32414" "39000"
"45010" "39000"
"45314" "39000"
"45443" "39000"
"45464" "39000"
"46293" "39000"
"30825" "39367"
"30401" "39500"
"30424" "39500"
"30784" "39500"
"45538" "39500"
"45539" "39500"
"45654" "39500"
"45681" "39500"
"30886" "39800"
"49"    "39900"
"97"    "39900"
"748"   "39900"
"1025"  "39900"
"1095"  "39900"
"29481" "39900"
"29686" "39900"
"29701" "39900"
"30045" "39900"
"30115" "39900"
"30153" "39900"
"30154" "39900"
"30171" "39900"
"30231" "39900"
"30232" "39900"
"30233" "39900"
"30234" "39900"
"30235" "39900"
"30239" "39900"
"30250" "39900"
"30251" "39900"
"30252" "39900"
"30253" "39900"
"30254" "39900"
"30288" "39900"
"30451" "39900"
"30575" "39900"
"30828" "39900"
"31009" "39900"
"36080" "39900"
"36704" "39900"
"36770" "39900"
"43405" "39900"
"45249" "39900"
"45525" "39900"
"45578" "39900"
"45619" "39900"
"45786" "39900"
"45874" "39900"
"45876" "39900"
"46092" "39900"
"46112" "39900"
"46266" "39900"
"30281" "39990"
"142"   "40000"
"30003" "40000"
"30004" "40000"
"30119" "40000"
"30601" "40000"
"31421" "40000"
"32072" "40000"
"45835" "42000"
"45870" "42000"
"45001" "42064"
"30023" "42500"
"30236" "42500"
"30249" "42500"
"30333" "42500"
"30686" "42500"
"30737" "42500"
"30738" "42500"
"30762" "42500"
"30874" "42500"
"32499" "42500"
"46194" "42500"
"46195" "42500"
"46196" "42500"
"884"   "42900"
"30662" "42900"
"30664" "42900"
"30666" "42900"
"30667" "42900"
"36529" "42900"
"43155" "42900"
"46106" "42900"
"46113" "42900"
"32619" "43000"
"43058" "43000"
"44904" "43000"
"45074" "43000"
"45194" "43000"
"45476" "43000"
"32570" "43400"
"30128" "43500"
"30000" "44000"
"30026" "44000"
"30741" "44000"
"46074" "44290"
"29883" "44300"
"30558" "44330"
"30896" "44500"
"46197" "44500"
"46198" "44500"
"45589" "44851"
"29279" "44900"
"30332" "44900"
"30841" "44900"
"44974" "44900"
"45307" "44900"
"29408" "44950"
"216"   "45000"
"603"   "45000"
"731"   "45000"
"29887" "45000"
"29888" "45000"
"29889" "45000"
"29890" "45000"
"45857" "45000"
"45911" "45000"
"45983" "45000"
"46172" "45000"
"46173" "45000"
"46174" "45000"
"46175" "45000"
"46176" "45000"
"46177" "45000"
"46178" "45000"
"46202" "45000"
"46242" "45000"
"46271" "45000"
"36066" "45360"
"94"    "45900"
"29979" "45900"
"30670" "45900"
"30671" "45900"
"30672" "45900"
"30673" "45900"
"30674" "45900"
"30675" "45900"
"30676" "45900"
"30677" "45900"
"31081" "45900"
"46099" "46000"
"29876" "46200"
"29733" "47000"
"30130" "47000"
"30740" "47000"
"36175" "47000"
"43143" "47000"
"44924" "47000"
"45126" "47000"
"45656" "47430"
"103"   "47500"
"30649" "47500"
"30716" "47500"
"30964" "47500"
"31155" "47500"
"43414" "47500"
"45883" "47650"
"30678" "47900"
"30679" "47900"
"30680" "47900"
"30681" "47900"
"30682" "47900"
"43008" "47900"
"44883" "47900"
"739"   "48000"
"30893" "48000"
"32232" "48000"
"32295" "48000"
"36607" "48000"
"43257" "48000"
"45872" "48000"
"30470" "48200"
"30594" "48500"
"31034" "48500"
"31064" "48500"
"31782" "48500"
"30826" "48520"
"43117" "50000"
"45411" "50000"
"45419" "50000"
"45584" "50000"
"45804" "50000"
"45805" "50000"
"46095" "50000"
"46134" "50000"
"46135" "50000"
"46264" "50000"
"46269" "50000"
"45815" "50500"
"36238" "50688"
"30089" "51000"
"30226" "51000"
"36732" "51000"
"45682" "51350"
"30005" "51500"
"30006" "51500"
"30090" "52000"
"30187" "52000"
"30776" "52000"
"30779" "52000"
"30782" "52000"
"45141" "52000"
"45418" "52000"
"45586" "52000"
"30116" "52250"
"43126" "52250"
"45479" "52250"
"29919" "52400"
"45436" "52400"
"30237" "52500"
"30238" "52500"
"30246" "52500"
"30248" "52500"
"30730" "52500"
"30731" "52500"
"30774" "52500"
"30775" "52500"
"30778" "52500"
"30780" "52500"
"30781" "52500"
"30789" "52500"
"30790" "52500"
"31730" "52500"
"32443" "52500"
"30602" "52680"
"31182" "52800"
"30036" "53000"
"30214" "53000"
"32325" "53000"
"45460" "53000"
"30709" "53528"
"29292" "53600"
"43470" "53600"
"29920" "53700"
"29921" "53700"
"29926" "53700"
"29927" "53700"
"29928" "53700"
"45437" "53700"
"45438" "53700"
"45439" "53700"
"45440" "53700"
"45441" "53700"
"1077"  "54000"
"30085" "54000"
"36266" "54000"
"45881" "54000"
"44982" "54400"
"30646" "54500"
"30561" "54850"
"654"   "54900"
"911"   "54900"
"30347" "54900"
"31104" "54900"
"31564" "54900"
"32005" "54900"
"36469" "54900"
"43071" "54900"
"45834" "54900"
"29443" "54950"
"30616" "54960"
"81"    "55000"
"30399" "70000"
"30880" "70000"
"31462" "70000"
"36314" "70000"
"36685" "70000"
"43219" "70000"
"45022" "70000"
"45621" "70000"
"45649" "70000"
"46201" "70000"
"30506" "70128"
"32580" "70500"
"46013" "70560"
"30515" "70750"
"30557" "70750"
"30204" "70875"
"30353" "71000"
"31079" "71000"
"32159" "71250"
"954"   "71500"
"32358" "71500"
"45495" "71500"
"29792" "71900"
"215"   "72000"
"31156" "72000"
"31324" "72000"
"32181" "72000"
"32586" "72000"
"36517" "72000"
"42994" "72000"
"44977" "72000"
"45736" "72000"
"45836" "72000"
"29162" "72400"
"886"   "72500"
"29111" "72500"
"29670" "72500"
"43170" "99975"
"44921" "99999"
"86"    "100000"
"255"   "100000"
"29325" "100000"
"30411" "100000"
"30815" "100000"
"30904" "100000"
"31230" "100000"
"31874" "100000"
"36083" "100000"
"45042" "100000"
"45543" "100000"
"45657" "100000"
"46005" "100000"
"46044" "100000"
"46045" "100000"
"46046" "100000"
"46091" "100000"
"45115" "101000"
"46067" "101600"
"29794" "102000"
"46048" "102600"
"45933" "102933"
"31508" "103000"
"31731" "103000"
"31972" "110000"
"32141" "110000"
"32233" "110000"
"32342" "110000"
"36357" "110000"
"36474" "110000"
"36705" "110000"
"45292" "110000"
"30840" "110175"
"30406" "110187"
"45655" "110187"
"29138" "110900"
"313"   "111000"
"45687" "111000"
"847"   "111900"
"29466" "111900"
"45499" "111900"
"29698" "112000"
"30387" "112000"
"31117" "112000"
"31906" "112000"
"32517" "112000"
"36767" "112000"
"45134" "112000"
"45591" "112000"
"30861" "112500"
"30987" "112500"
"32550" "112500"
"36377" "112500"
"36641" "112500"
"31550" "112900"
"32149" "112900"
"45772" "112912"
"30404" "113000"
"45937" "113000"
"45214" "113900"
"517"   "114000"
"31727" "114000"
"45704" "114432"
"101"   "114500
"32493" "120000"
"36338" "120000"
"36340" "120000"
"36371" "120000"
"36561" "120000"
"44996" "120000"
"45155" "120000"
"45612" "120000"
"45757" "120000"
"46116" "120000"
"46061" "120215"
"614"   "120500"
"31502" "120500"
"45737" "120897"
"751"   "121000"
"1074"  "121000"
"32190" "121000"
"46087" "121497"
"46123" "121500"
"30129" "121800"
"36183" "121800"
"29758" "151500"
"30643" "151588"
"45753" "151686"
"30122" "152000"
"44928" "152000"
"29221" "152500"
"31806" "152900"
"45917" "152900"
"36535" "153000"
"45854" "153000"
"30710" "153300"
"29597" "153400"
"36523" "153400"
"36502" "153700"
"46086" "153700"
"30519" "153900"
"43013" "153900"
"31303" "154000"
"43070" "154030"
"29328" "154500"
"36150" "154500"
"412"   "154900"
"444"   "154900"
"646"   "154900"
"29260" "154900"
"29289" "154900"
"29717" "154900"
"29740" "154900"
"29819" "154900"
"31353" "154900"
"36364" "154900"
"32320" "199500"
"45729" "199500"
"253"   "199800"
"254"   "199800"
"19"    "199900"
"369"   "199900"
"629"   "199900"
"630"   "199900"
"636"   "199900"
"877"   "199900"
"891"   "199900"
"958"   "199900"
"30863" "340000"
"31207" "340000"
"43187" "340900"
"43190" "340900"
"43194" "340900"
"36673" "341000"
"43304" "341000"
"36669" "341500"
"31626" "342000"
"36202" "342000"
"36388" "342000"
"221"   "342250"
"43476" "342500"
"160"   "343000"
"31088" "343000"
"36672" "343900"
"36534" "343950"
"44958" "344000"
"30383" "344500"
"45638" "344500"
"29810" "344800"
"46"    "344900"
"554"   "344900"
"29435" "344900"
"31020" "344900"
"480"   "345000"
"30697" "345000"
"31458" "595000"
"36406" "596900"
"45565" "598000"
"61"    "599000"
"322"   "599000"
"29603" "599000"
"30467" "599000"
"31174" "599000"
"31410" "599000"
"31521" "599000"
"31720" "599000"
"36745" "599000"
"43102" "599000"
"31582" "599500"
"850"   "599800"
"31417" "599900"
"36545" "599900"
"45083" "600000"
"45425" "600000"
"45721" "600000"
"1151"  "609900"
"32193" "609900"
"976"   "612000"
"32424" "615000"
"43421" "615000"
"44975" "615000"
"298"   "619500"
"419"   "621212"
"30447" "621212"
"43313" "624900"
```

The thing I have noticed about this is that the millions do not exceed the top most value if you were to roll off the last zero. Not sure how to solve this or really what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All the values you show are between 7000 and 624900, which are all values between the conditions in your query, greater than 1 and less than 625000. None are in the millions. Are you mis-reading the values?

Comment: Have a read about data types.

Comment: @Strawberry, That's not the problem. By comparing to integer constants, MySQL implicitly casts a string value to an integer. So `'425000' < 625000` is true, but `'4250000' < 625000` is false. But a comparison between two strings like `'4250000 < '625000'` is true because they are compared lexically, instead of by their integer value.

Comment: @BillKarwin You've accidentally solved a problem I was struggling with this morning. I was wondering why my index was being ignored when searching a varchar column for an integer value. I expected MySQL to convert the integer to string and preserve the index, but now I realize that string to integer conversion is more likely to produce expected behavior. (I'm actually checking for equality, but I understand it's a general rule for implicit conversions.)

Comment: @shmosel I suggest you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: @BillKarwin I was just reading that. I assume this falls into the final category: *In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.* Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's right.

Comment: Oh my goodness you guys are right! I was having this issue but I suppose the fix I put in place did work. Well I am very sorry for wasting everyone's time. You guys rock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of posting an answer:

The query result you showed is correct, all values are between the range criteria in your query. I think you were misreading the values accidentally.